# What is the behavior of "+ +" (plus-space-plus) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Someone send me a joke with this piece of code:

```js
console.log(('b' + 'a' + + 'a' + 'a').toLowerCase());  // returns "banana"
```

Trying to understand this result, I noticed that this is a play around the fact that this expression returns "NaN" and JavaScript converts it to string. In short:

```js
console.log(+ + 'anything');  // returns NaN
```

So far so good.

However, I really don't understand why the expression `+ + string` (plus-space-plus-string) is valid and why it returns NaN.  In my understanding, there is a syntax error in this expression (operator followed by other operator).

Comment: It's the complimentary operator to `-n`, e.g. `-1`…

Comment: Actually, it is the unary operator. In short, `+'string'` tries to convert string to number, and since it fails, it returns NaN. When there's a second/third plus sign, you're just repeating the same operation twice. So the expression in the beginning of this question is evaluated as `'b' + 'a' + (+'a') + 'a'`. I really hate JavaScript.